# R - convert reporting structure to JSON

Tags: json, r, tree, nested

I'm having trouble getting some reporting structure data (about 300 cases) in the JSON format I need it to be in so I can pop it into a d3 tree network. I can't find a function to automate this conversion- most of the resources out there use a clustering function (e.g., `hclust`), but my data is merely an unweighted edge list, so such functions do not work. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Sample of data source:

```
jobTitle    reportsTo
CTO         CEO
CPO         CEO
Director    CPO
Manager     Director
```

JSON output needed:

```
  "name": "CEO",
      "children": [
        {
            "name": "CPO",
            "children": [
              {
                  "name": "Director",
                   "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Manager",
                             "children": []
                        }
                   ]
              }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "CTO",
            "children": []
        }
      ]
```

Answer (score 5):

See https://github.com/timelyportfolio/d3r for a helper function to build/nest your data.  Here is an example using the data your provided.

```
#install.packages("d3r")
library(d3r)

df <- read.table(
  textConnection(
'jobTitle    reportsTo
CTO         CEO
CPO         CEO
Director    CPO
Manager     Director
'  ),
  header = TRUE,
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

d3r::d3_nest(df)
# or it seems we should change order first
d3r::d3_nest(df[,c(2,1)])
```

Note, you show empty arrays for `children: []`.  `d3_nest` eliminates empty children.